# save the content from a jtextpane in derby?

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, derby, jtextpane

How can I save the content from a jtextpane in derby?
I am writing a software  which has a jtetxpane and derby  db , when i save the text as String, at the moment of read it, it lose  all fonts styles like bold or italic.
i save the string whit a preparedStatemend.so  how can i save the text in derby? i am thinking in a blob, so how can save a  blob from the jtextpane and read it? or how can i save it? 
how can i fix it?
sorry if my english is bad.

Insert:

```
        try {
        String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
        String dbName = "bdprueba";
        String dbParam = "create=true"; //la base de datos se creará si no existe todavía
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";" + dbParam;
        String sql="insert into persona (texto) values(?)";

        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL);
        PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        st.setString(1, texto.getText());
        st.executeUpdate();
        conn.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Select:

```
    try {
        String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
        String dbName = "bdprueba";
        String dbParam = "create=true"; 
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:" + dbName +"" ;
        Class.forName(driver);
        Connection conn =  DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL); 
        Statement st = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs =  st.executeQuery("select texto from persona");
        while(rs.next())
        {      
            texto.setText(rs.getString("Texto"));            
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Editor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Grasias a ambos

thank you both

Comment: it lose all fonts styles like bold or italic. everything depends of how is Highlighter applied to thw Document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you save the string then read it just after saving and compare both strings? If they are the same then problem is not DB part.

I would check editor kit of the destination JtextPane. It must be the same as in the source JTextPane. If strings are different then it's DB problem.

Look at the http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/Saveimagetoderbydatabase.htm example. You can store your text (bytes of the string) rather than image.

Answer (score 0):

Try working with the document instead of the getText()

```
jtextpane.getDocument()
```